# C++ std:getline seems to be messing up a non ASCII character in input file

Tags: c++

I have this simple piece of code that converts a csv file into a 2D string array.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> parseCSV(std::istream& inputStream)
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > parsedCsv;
    while (std::getline(inputStream, line))
    {
        std::stringstream lineStream(line);
        std::string cell;
        std::vector<std::string> parsedRow;
        while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, ',')) {
            parsedRow.push_back(cell);
        }
        parsedCsv.push_back(parsedRow);
    }
    return parsedCsv;
}
```

When it encounters this character `’` which is different than `'` (*it was used in the input file as an apostrophe, but it kind of isn't. It's probably non-ASCII*), my code replaces it with something like `ΓÇÖ`

Is there a way I could retain the original character?

**Edit: 12/14/21**
To check for OS dependency, I used these simple lines

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    str = "Amanda's";
    cout<<str<<endl;
    str = "Amanda’s";
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Using g++ on linux (Ubuntu), the output was fine

```
Amanda's
Amanda’s
```

Using Visual Studio on Windows 10, the output was problematic

```
Amanda's
AmandaΓÇÖs
```

On Windows I tried printing into a file, instead of command prompt. Using these lines.

```
int writeCSV(const std::string& outFileName, std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& textMatrix)
    {
        std::ofstream out(outFileName);
        for (auto& row : textMatrix) {
            for (auto col : row)
                out << col << ',';
            out << '\n';
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Even in the file the character is messed up.

Comment: ***Is there a way I could retain the original character?*** How do you know this change is happening? Perhaps the problem is in your terminal or how you are displaying the result

Comment: Your code does not manipulate characters. It manipulates bytes. And from a quick look, most probably it writes exactly the same bytes it read. Now the killer question: whatever program you used to write the input, and whatever program you use to read the output, how do they interpret those bytes? If their interpretation does not match, they won't agree on the meaning.

Comment: You two raise a good point. For debugging I tried to put a simple std::cout << cell; right after I did a getline on cell. Could cout be messing up the character instead? How would I check for that?

Comment: How are you printing it?  To a terminal/command prompt?  And which OS?

Comment: To the terminal on Windows 10. I am using Visual Studio 2019 to compile and run the program.